# How do I create a view from a MySQL table that counts a specific condition in each column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is something like this:

```
Name    Alice    Bob    Carl    Dan    ...
Foo     2        2      0       1
Bar     1        2      2       0  
...
```

What I want is to make a view (or just do a query) that will tell me how many 0s, 1s, and 2s there are in Alice's, Bob's, etc. column. So I want to get a table that looks like this:

```
Name     0s   1s   2s
Alice    5    2    3
Bob      7    1    4
Carl     3    ...etc.
```

How can I do this? The values in the cells can only ever be 0, 1 or 2, so it doesn't need to be general for any arbitrary data. The table I need to do this with has about 70 columns and 1250 rows.

Comment: I think you should normalize your structure first.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: @Peter means that your database structure seems odd.  You typically should not have columns that represent different instances of the same type of object (in this case a person).  My guess is you should have a table for your people and then a table or tables that relate to it to store your other data.  In this case it is hard to recommend a structure, as I have no idea what `foo` and `bar` represent.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather painful to use the data structure you have.  Basically, you can do something like this:

```
select 'Alice' as name, sum(Alice = 0) as Zeros, sum(Alice = 1) as Ones, Sum(Alice = 2) as Twos
from table t
union all
select 'Bob' as name, sum(Bob = 0) as Zeros, sum(Bob = 1) as Ones, Sum(Bob = 2) as Twos
from table t
union all
. . .
```

That is, create a subquery for each of the rows in the output.

Note:  this is probably the simplest way to achieve what you want.  If you have a large table, there might be other methods that perform better.

Also, you can use a spreadsheet to generate the code for each of the subqueries.  That can make it much easier to write the query.

EDIT:

You would be much better off structuring the table with three columns:

- Name
- Whatever Foo/Bar should be called
- Value

Then you could do this relatively easily with conditional aggregation.

Comment: Thanks. If I was doing this from scratch, how would you recommend I structure the original table?